# RNG, Unity UI text to Script

Tags: c#, user-interface, random

I'm trying to code a text based game using the unity engine. I've got my errors narrowed down to three.

> Error CS1061: Type UnityEngine.UI.Text does not contain a definition for HP of type Unity.Text
>
> Error CS1061: Type Unity.Engine.Random does not contain a definition for Next and no extension method Next of type UnityEngine.Random

I can narrow down the errors to these lines:

> Next error:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
                int month = rnd.Next(1, 13);
```

> HP Error: `public Text HP;`
> `text.HP = "HP: " + healthPoints;`

I really don't understand the RNG for C#. C++ no problem I know what I need to include for it. All the searches I've done for C# I can't figure the RNG out or what's needed.

As for the HP I have a text object on my UI named HP. I've linked it to the script, but where previously the engine listed SCRIPT and then TEXT below on main screen there's no TEXT area to drag HP into. I'm not sure how to change that UI object through my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HP problem is caused because you're calling it the wrong way. It's supposed to be

```
HP.Text = "HP: " + healthPoints;
```

The problem with Random is you don't call it like that in Unity, you call it like this:

`int month = Random.Range(0,13);`

Good luck with your game!

Comment: You are awesome! Thank You! Now the only thing I'm getting is NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TextController.Update () (at Assets/TextController.cs:30)

Comment: I'd really need to see what you have in TextController.cs at line 30! NullReferenceException basically means you're trying to work with something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I figured it out the missing links under Inspector finally showed up and now everything is working as it should! Thanks again!